# Correctly outputting JavaScript Variables in jQuery function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**I originally thought this was a WordPress issue - but realize after hours of attempts - this might be a more general JavaScript question**

I've been struggling with this for a few hours and am hoping that you can point me in the right direction. I've been using [this](http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/) tutorial to help me understand how `wp_localize_script` works (this is a WordPress function that allows you to pass PHP variables to JS files). First, I enqueued my script as such:

```
function of_load_scripts() {

    if (!is_admin()) {

        if(is_front_page()) {
            global $post;
            wp_register_script('supersized.shutter', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/mylibs/supersized.shutter.min.js', 'jquery');
            wp_enqueue_script('supersized.shutter');
            wp_register_script('shutter_home', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/shutter-home.js', 'jquery');
            wp_enqueue_script('shutter_home');
        }

        $tester = get_field('text');

        // Add some parameters for the JS.
        wp_localize_script(
            'shutter_home',
            'shutter',
            array(
                'testerjs' => $tester
            )
        );
    }

}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'of_load_scripts');
```

I've verified this is outputting to the HTML source of the page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var shutter = {"testerjs":"This is a test value"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Then, in my `shutter-home.js` file, I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var testerjs = shutter.testerjs;
    alert(testerjs);

    $.supersized({

        // Functionality
        slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
        autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
        start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
        stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
        random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
        slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
        transition              :   1,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
        transition_speed        :   700,        // Speed of transition
        new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
        pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
        keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
        performance             :   0,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
        image_protect           :   0,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

        // Size & Position                         
        min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
        min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
        vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
        horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
        fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
        fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
        fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

        // Components                           
        slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
        thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
        thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation

        // Components                           
        slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg'},  
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-2.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-2.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-3.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-3.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-1.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-1.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg'},
                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg'}
                                    ],
        // Theme
        progress_bar            :   0           // Slide bar that shows duration until next transition

    });

});
```

which correctly just outputs `This is a test value` (as I did a quick `alert()`). The problem I'm having is passing this value within the `$.supersized` function (specifically in the `slides` area in the `image` position). This may be a general JS question - but how would I go about sticking in that `testerjs` variable into that area? I've tried things like:

```
{image : ''+ testerjs + '', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg'},
```

with no dice. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*`testerjs` is just an example variable - it would normally hold an image URL - so just used for example purposes*

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if your alert shows the correct value. There is no need to concatenate with empty strings though.

Comment: Hi @PhilParsons - I guess what I'm looking for is a quick snippet I should be using in `{image : ''+ testerjs + '', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg'}` that should correctly output that variable (as I'm unsure of the syntax and have been scouring the internet for quite some time without luck). Should the initialization of the variable be within the `$.supersized()` function? Thanks!

Comment: Bleh I'm stupid - it was because I was outputting `This is a test value` instead of an actual image URL that was producing the unexpected results. Okay - a more relevant question to add-on to this would be (let me know if I should start a new question) -- can you pass a PHP function to JS? So - in this example, I'd have an array of values I'd `implode()` to individually set each slide. Thanks!

Comment: @Zach: What do you mean by "pass a PHP function to JS"?  JavaScript cannot directly call a PHP function (it can via AJAX).

Comment: @Zach As long as your shutter-home.js file is included in your page below the script tag wordpress is putting out you can just access it like `{image : shutter.testerjs, thumb : 'http://...'}`

Comment: @PhilParsons I got the first part to work (my own stupidity - thanks for your help with that). The other part was I would have an array of values (PHP) that I'd like to be able to pass to JS (so it would output each image source URL separately). Let me know if I'm way off with that. Thanks!

Comment: @Zach I have added a possible solution for passing an array of objects as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't just pass an array of objects to be built as a JavaScript object by the `wp_localize_script` function and pass that as the slides parameter you could build up your array of URLs in php such as

```
$slides = array(
  array('image' => 'http://...', 'thumb' => 'http://...'),
  array('image' => 'http://...', 'thumb' => 'http://...'),
  array('image' => 'http://...', 'thumb' => 'http://...')
);
```

`json_encode` this array which will then give you the data structure you require for the slides parameter in your JavaScript.

```
wp_localize_script(
  'shutter_home',
  'shutter',
  array( 'slides' => json_encode($slides) )
);
```

Then you should just be able to parse this and use it as the slides parameter of the object passed to the $.supersized function.

```
slides: $.parseJSON(shutter.slides.replace('&quot;', '"')
```

Best bet would be to do the parsing before using the resulting object so that you can catch any errors that may occur with possibly malformed JSON.

---

**edit:** Corrected code from snippet provided in comments.

You are appending each image/thumb object as a string so these will be strings still in the js. Also you had a couple of syntax errors in the JavaScript for the slides parameter (missing parenthesis and a semi-colon) and I removed the unnecessary string replacement.

```
// php
$imageArray = array();
if(get_field('image_container')) {
    while(the_repeater_field('image_container')) {
        $imageSource = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full');
        $thumbSource = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'background_thumb');
        array_push($imageArray, array('image'=> $imageSource[0], 'thumb' => $thumbSource[0]));
    }
}

$imageOutput = json_encode($imageArray);

// Add some parameters for the JS.
wp_localize_script(
    'shutter_home',
    'shutter',
    array(
        'imageOutputjs' => $imageOutput
    )
);

//js
slides : $.parseJSON(shutter.imageOutputjs)
```

Comment: Hi @PhilParsons,
I'm a little unfamiliar with JSON - but this is what I have so far: http://snippi.com/s/shpb2hd Let me know if I'm way off here or if you have any suggestions. I really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Also - I tried using `implode()` which seems to write the data fine -- but I'm wondering if it is an issue with the slashes being escaped (see http://snippi.com/s/swcv0t3 for reference) in the HTML source that is making this still not work. Thanks!

Comment: @Zach I have edited and added the code from your snippet to my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! Honestly a little foggy on `json_encode()` but it's something I need to look into. Appreciate all your help on this, have a great day!